# Java: Code explain

Tags: java

Can someone explain to me how the parameter in below code work? It is very confusing to me.

```
if (enemy == null) {
    playField = new RoundRectangle2D.Double( WALLAVOID, WALLAVOID,
    getBattleFieldWidth() - 2 * WALLAVOID, 
    getBattleFieldHeight() - 2 * WALLAVOID, 50, 50);
```

Comment: Please tell us which part is confusing you. This code is calling a a constructor on the `Double` class with 6 parameters. This class is an inner class to the class `RoundRectangle2D`.

Comment: The part i can't understand is from the parameter (WALLAVOID,......, 50, 50). What is the fundamental behind using this type of parameter?

Comment: WALLAVOID is just a constant variable, declared somewhere. I imagine it's declared in an imported class, as a commonly used value or something. The third line of code in your original post is just a calculation, so the value passed as a parameter is the result of that calculation, not the calculation itself. For instance if you were to call this `myMethod(2+3)` the actual resulting call to myMethod would only have the parameter `5`, e.g `myMethod(5)`, since the calculation is performed before the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
if (enemy == null) {
    double width = getBattleFieldWidth() - 2 * WALLAVOID;
    double height = getBattleFieldHeight() - 2 * WALLAVOID;
    playField = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(WALLAVOID, WALLAVOID, width, height, 50, 50);
```

When you look at the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RoundRectangle2D.Double.html#RoundRectangle2D.Double(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double)) you will see the explanation of the six parameters that this constructor uses. What the actual values are, is hard to say without the context of the application. `WALLAVOID` is a constant (if coding conventions are followed correctly) and was defined somewhere earlier in the application.

Comment: Thank a lots for your answer. I finally understand it :)